# Sitemap PHP Mysql Split 45000

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

include 'conexao.php';
include 'acoes.php';

$sql = mysql_query("select nome, nota from aluno");

$a = 0;
while ($string = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    if ($a == 0)
    {
        $data = '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9     http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">';
        $data .= '<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>';
        $data .= '<urlset>';
    }

    $data .= '<url>';
    $data .= '<loc>http://www.escola.com.br/' . removerosAcentos($string['nome']);
    $data .= $string['nota'] . '</loc>';
    $data .= '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>';
    $data .= '</url>';
    $a += 1;
    if ($a >= 45000)
    {
        $data .= '</urlset>';
        $a = 0;

        $nome_arquivo = uniqid();
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . $nome_arquivo . '.xml"');
        header('Content-type: "text/xml"; charset="utf8"');
        readfile($nome_arquivo . '.xml');

    }
}
?>
```

The data in the file is stuck in the variable $data, just use its data to insert the information in the XML

How to continue with the code by creating the sitemap with 45,000 records per sitemap (sitemap1.xml, sitemap2.xml)

Can anyone help?

Comment: `45.000` to PHP is a decimal, use `45000`. Look at paginating your query. You also are better to use `>=` your `==` probably never occurs.

Comment: Changed in code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a offset and limit in your SQL-statement.

```
$part = (int) $_GET['part']; // Use http://domain/url?part=0 for first part and so on
if ($part < 0) { 
    $part = 0; // To prevent illegal query
}

$perPart = 45000;
$offset = $part * $perPart;

$sql = mysql_query("select nome, nota from aluno limit $offset , $perPart");
```

Note: the `mysql_`-functions are deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore when writing new code. See the red warning on [php.net/mysql_query](http://php.net/mysql_query). Consider migrating to MySQLi or PDO.